# Appcelerator - Getting geolocation information and turning into a URL

Tags: ios, geolocation, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm still very new to appcelerator but I'm trying to do a small experiment with geolocation. I have some code similar to below, which returns the long and lat to the console. What I would like to is get the long and lat and append them to a URL, e.g http://www.mywebsite.com/lat/long.

I've tried creating a simple alert to show me the current location in the but all it says is Alert: [object GeolocationModule].

Could somebody point me in the right direction so I can learn some more? Thank you

```
if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
Titanium.Geolocation.purpose = 'Get Current Location';
Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
    if (e.error) {
        Ti.API.error('Error: ' + e.error);
    } else {
        Ti.API.info(e.coords);
    }
});
} else {

    alert('Please enable location services');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you need to follow the API documentation:

You can have a look at the LocationResults page: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/LocationResults which leads you to LocationCoordinates: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/LocationCoordinates

There you can see, that you can use `e.coords.latitude` or `longitude` to get the values. Or have a look at the console output. It should show you a JSON output with the key-value pairs.

Once you have the values you can create a HTTP request (demo: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/HTTPClient_and_the_Request_Lifecycle) and open your page:

```
var url = "https://www.appcelerator.com/"+e.coords.longitude+"/"+e.coords.latitude;
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
        // this function is called when data is returned from the server and available for use
        // this.responseText holds the raw text return of the message (used for text/JSON)
        // this.responseXML holds any returned XML (including SOAP)
        // this.responseData holds any returned binary data
        Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);
        alert('success');
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        // this function is called when an error occurs, including a timeout
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('error');
    },
    timeout:5000  /* in milliseconds */
});
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();  // request is actually sent with this statement
```

or if you plan to use more request have a look at RESTe (https://github.com/jasonkneen/RESTe) which is an awesome library that makes it easy to create API requests

Comment: Thank you very much, thats helped a lot. I've managed to create a variable within the location function that prints out an alert with the URL I need with the lat/long inserted in the correct place. Is there a way to access this variable from outside the function? I need to use it to load a webview. I've tried using Ti.App.myvariable name but that doesnt seem to work outside of the function.

Comment: Sure, you can create a variable outside the function (above line 1) and set it inside the getcurrentposition. Or call a function that is outside like this `callURL(long,lat)` and put the xhr stuff inside a `function callURL(long, lat){}`

Comment: Thank you, I'm not too sure I understand you 100%, sorry. How would I set the variable within getcurrentposition? I've tried various ways and none of them seem to be working.

Comment: Its a basic javascript problem, not related to ti. See something like this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp (global scope) You just asign the variable and declare it outside the function.

Comment: I see thank you. Could you explain a little more about putting the xhr stuff in a function? Do you mean the xhr.open part?

Comment: please see your other thread for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37468392/5193915 But again: some code basics are missing. So it would be best get some more basics in javascript or start with an easier app project first until you have a basic setup and then work with gps and api calls. Good luck and perhaps join the ti-slack group for quick help, too